# What is the restriction of a locally ringed space to an open subset U?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, ringed-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space and $U\subset X$ an open subset.

For the definition of a scheme one considers $(U, \mathcal{O}_X|_U)$. What is $ \mathcal{O}_X|_U$ formally? Is it just the sheaf of all $\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ for all $V \subset U$ with the induced restriction maps?

Comment: Yes, exactly, $O_X |_U (V) = O_X(V)$ with induced restriction map.

Comment: Hi, I am extremely interested in the question you have posted on, and deleted from, the philosophy website. Can you please contact me at nir@winpdb.org?

Comment: Dear Nir, Thank you for your interest, I just posted a better written version of my question on philosophy stack exchange